# How would I extract the value of this HTML element attribute with Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, html, screen-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-scraping

I am developing a small tool to scrape a webpage. I am using [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). I would like to fetch the class id from the page. The HTML code looks something like this:

```
<span class='class_id' id='New_line'></span>
```

How would I obtain `class_id`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the following example may help you?

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as B
>>> s = B("<span class='class_id' id='New_line'></span>")
>>> s.span.attrs
[(u'class', u'class_id'), (u'id', u'New_line')]
```

Answer (score 5):

*This answer refers to an older version of the question where `beautifulsoup` has not been mentioned*

You can use LXML and iterate over all elements asking them for the value of their "class" attribute. LXML is a library for parsing XML documents.

Like, for example:

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.parse(filename).getroot()

for span in root.iterdescendants("span"):
    cls = span.attrib.get("class")
```

Comment: I am using `beautifulsoup` library to parse the HTML. Do you think I can ge the get the class attribute with it ?

Comment: Maybe you look [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html) for "The attributes of tags".